# Django queue reincarnated monitor Process-1:228 after sudden death

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sentry, cron-task

I've installed and configured Django-Q 1.0.2 (on Django 1.11.10 with Redis 1.0.1 and Python 3.6.9). This is my Cluster configuration:

Q_CLUSTER = {
'bulk': 5,
'recycle': 500,
'compress': True,
'save_limit': 500,
'queue_limit': 500,
'label': 'Django Q',
'attempt_count': 1
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is your question?   What do you mean by your title?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.